# Strange output address

Tags: transactions, blockchain, address

Looking in transaction https://blockchain.info/it/tx/ecd1a64432367a1962eadd90ec12cfb6c5f6920075b10a62dbda7488c5688e44 i see strange output address like this: bc1q8r0m7ymhf2smspeqgzwj79e89kvmgwqasg5glskugrrzc7qv57tq2e6sjf

what kind are?

Comment: Just one of the new native segwit addresses starting with „bc1“

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pebwindkraft comment, it's the new bitcoin segwit address (bech32), it's supported on bitcoin-core v0.16.

Bech32 is a segwit address format specified by BIP 0173. While this address format has been included in some implementations, as of December 2017.

If you would know more about it [watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqiN9VFE4CU)

Comment: Yup, I should have answered this way :-) +1! There were two interesting discussions in bitcointalk: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2624630.msg26762627#msg26762627 and https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2664728.0 - just for completing background discussions.

Comment: Hahaha, Yeah, consider it as your answer. BTW answer edited.